# tic tac toe and minimax algorithm

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I am trying to make tic tac toe using minimax algorithm. I am referring to the following code. But I am not understanding the use of [0]. Please explain the following line:

```
value = self.move(x,y).minimax(not player)[0]
```

taking the reference of the code given below. And also tell the use of returning "None" along with +1 or -1 or 0. Please do not negative vote my question or I will be blocked.

```
def minimax(self, player):
    if self.won():
      if player:
        return (-1,None)
      else:
        return (+1,None)
    elif self.tied():
      return (0,None)
    elif player:
      best = -2,0
      for x,y in self.fields:
        if self.fields[x,y]==self.empty:
          value = self.move(x,y).minimax(not player)[0]
          if value>best[0]:
            best = (value,(x,y))
      return best
    else:
      best = (+2,None)
      for x,y in self.fields:
        if self.fields[x,y]==self.empty:
          value = self.move(x,y).minimax(not player)[0]
          if value<best[0]:
            best = (value,(x,y))
      return best
```

Comment: Use this for additional help:
http://cwoebker.com/posts/tic-tac-toe

Answer (score 1):

> But I am not understanding the use of [0]

The function returns a tuple of (value,(x,y)), so accessing the 0th element of that will give you `value`.

The function returns `None` in the value when the game is over, since no new move is made. The `value` will be who won (with 0 meaning they tied).

Answer (score 1):

`minimax` returns a tuple; the statement in question is calling `minimax`, taking the first element of the returned tuple (the `[0]` bit) and assigning that to `best`.